# Why $\frac{1}{12}$ arises in this summatory function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am very interested in finding an answer to some questions related to [the divisor summatory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#:%7E:text=In%20number%20theory%2C%20the%20divisor,are%20sometimes%20called%20divisor%20problems.). I am hope for your help.

Let:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    f(n,x) &= 2 \Big(n\big(\ln{x} + \gamma + \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} + \frac{1}{120x^4}\big)-\\
    &- \frac{1}{2}\big(x-(\ln{x}+\gamma + \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{12x^2} + \frac{1}{120x^4})\big) \Big) - x^2 
    \approx\\
    &\approx (2n+1)H_x - x^2 - x
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Denote:
\begin{equation}
S(n) = \sqrt{n} - \Big(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{2\sqrt{n}} \Big)
\end{equation}
Let's define the functions:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&f_{1}(n) = f(n,S(n))\\
&f_{2}(n) = f(n,\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)\\
&f^{*}_{1}(n) = f_{1}(n) - \frac{1}{12}\\
&f^{*}_{2}(n) = f_{2}(n) + \frac{1}{12}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
also define:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F(n,f(n)) = \sum_{x=1}^{n}\Big(D(n)-f(n)\Big)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
D(n) = \sum_{x=1}^{n}\Big\lfloor \frac{n}{x} \Big\rfloor
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
-- divisor summatory function.

Now let's draw plots for the following functions:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&F_1(n) = F(n,f_1(n))\\
&F_2(n) = F(n, f_2(n))\\
&F^{*}_1(n) = F(n, f^{*}_1(n))\\
&F^{*}_2(n) = F(n, f^{*}_2(n))
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We will get for $n=1..10^3$:

[image: plot for n=1..10^3]

and for $n=1..10^6$:

[image: plot for n=1..10^6]

**Questions**

1. I'm curious why $ \pm \frac {1} {12} $ shifts the plots of functions
   $ F_1 $, $ F_2 $ to the coordinate axis so precisely?
2. Is it true that the functions $ F^{*}_1 $ and $ F^{*}_2 $ will
   change sign an infinite number of times?
3. Why does a function  $F^{*}_1(n)-F^{*}_2(n)$ fit quite well with
   next expression?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
L(n) = \frac{3}{4\pi}\log{n} + \frac{1}{5 \pi}\sqrt{n} \sin{\big(2\pi\sqrt{n} + \pi\big)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

plot:

[image]

So if these questions are quite empirical and non-professional, I will move this post to math.stackexchange.

**Edit**
[Plotting code](https://pastebin.com/NL237jHc)

Comment: Why all this obfuscation ? $f(n,x)$ is essentially equal to $(2n+1)H_x-x-x^2$, where $H_x=\psi(x)+\gamma$ is the harmonic sum generalized to all complex numbers, anf if I am not mistaken $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: Henri Cohen, Yes, of course, thanks for your comment! I fixed the post. I wrote formula (1) as in my plotting code (I push it on https://pastebin.com/NL237jHc). I understand that 1/(120n^4) can be removed from there. I thought there might be an rounding error and decided to write it that way instead using harmonic number.